# Bootstrap Typeahead select any words from query

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, typeahead, bootstrap-typeahead

I use the following code to get source for a Bootstrap Typehead Textbox:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("input[id$='txtSearchWhat']").typeahead({
            source: function (typeahead, query) {
                $.get("http://localhost:5980/Services/AutoComplete.svc/WordLookup", {     text: typeahead },
                function (data) {

                    return query(data.d);
                });

            }
        });
    });
```

That works fine with a list (example)

```
- Pizza
- Lasagne
- Pasta
```

Typing eg "P", it showes up Pizza and Lasagne
Typing eg "as" it showes Lasagne and Pasta

What i need to know, and i did not found a answer nowhere, and no idea how to do it is:

How I can do, that with the list above, typing eg "I want a Pizza", Pizza show up.
Or eg Pizza or Lasagne show Pizza and Lasagne.
In other words. How to implement the typeahead, that it selects from multiple words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the options you can pass in to the typeahead is a custom matcher function.

```
matcher: function( item ) {
  // The 'item' parameter is any item in your list (e.g. "Pizza" )
  // Use this.query to access the search string (e.g. "I want a Pizza")
  // return true if this.query matches item through your custom logic
}
```

Comment: do you know a page with examples of matcher ?

Comment: This page shows an implementation of the matcher function: http://tatiyants.com/how-to-use-json-objects-with-twitter-bootstrap-typeahead/